# junit.framework.AssertionFailedError while testing back button on android

Tags: android, android-activity, robotium

i am new to Robotium.I'm facing an issue **"junit.framework.AssertionFailedError"** while executing the  test case which using Robotium.Test scenario is checking Back button functionality.here's my code

```
    package com.example.test;
import android.test.ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2;
import android.widget.EditText;

import com.jayway.android.robotium.solo.Solo;
import com.example.app.R;
import com.example.app.LoginActivity;
import com.example.app.AccountCardListActivity;
import com.example.app.ReceiptListActivity;
import com.example.app.WithdrawalListActivity;


public class Back_Concerto_425 extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<LoginActivity>{




    public Back_Concerto_425() {
        super(LoginActivity.class);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }


    private Solo solo;


    protected void setUp() throws Exception
    {
        solo = new Solo(getInstrumentation(), getActivity());

    }

    public void testbackbutton()
    {

        solo.enterText(0, "username");
        solo.enterText(1, "password");
        solo.clickOnButton(0);
        solo.waitForActivity("com.example.app.WithdrawalListActivity", 3000);
        assertTrue(solo.searchText("WithdrawlListActivity"));
        solo.clickOnButton("View Receipts");
        solo.waitForActivity("com.example.app.ReceiptListActivity",3000);
        assertTrue(solo.searchText("Receipts"));
        solo.goBackToActivity("com.example.app.WithdrawalListActivity");
        assertTrue(solo.searchButton("View Receipts"));
        assertTrue(solo.searchButton("New withdrawal"));


    }


    public void tearDown() throws Exception
    {

        try
        {
            solo.finalize();
        }
        catch (Throwable e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        super.tearDown();
    }

    }
```

Here's My error log

```
[INFO]     Start [15/16]: com.ncr.mobile.mcw.test.WithdrawlListActivityTest#testreceiptsbutton
[INFO]     FAILURE:com.ncr.mobile.mcw.test.WithdrawlListActivityTest#testreceiptsbutton
[INFO]     junit.framework.AssertionFailedError
at com.ncr.mobile.mcw.test.WithdrawlListActivityTest.testreceiptsbutton(WithdrawlListActivityTest.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestCase.runMethod(InstrumentationTestCase.java:214)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestCase.runTest(InstrumentationTestCase.java:199)
at android.test.ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2.runTest(ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2.java:192)
at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:190)
at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:175)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner.onStart(InstrumentationTestRunner.java:555)
at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1584)
```

Please let me know if there is any mistake in my code.

Comment: Where is the testreceiptsbutton?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

once one of my friend faced the same problem he resolved by giving timeout period,similarly you haven't mentioned timeout period in `waitactivity method` or by just using `WaitActivity` method without `timeout argument`.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

This is the expected result when using assertTrue(boolean condition) and the condition is 'False':

> public static void assertTrue (boolean condition)
>
> Asserts that a condition is true. **If it isn't it throws an AssertionFailedError.**

[Android Developers - Assert](http://file:///D:/Android_SDK/docs/reference/junit/framework/Assert.html#assertTrue%28java.lang.String,%20boolean%29)

Other options that you can use are:

```
assertTrue (String message, boolean condition)
```

- with your custom String message you will have information what and where is going wrong

```
assertEquals(true, boolean condition);
```